# Computer wont install Windows Vista or Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-vista

I had Windows Vista on my computer and wanted to upgrade to Windows 7 and thought that I would format my computer since it had been awhile. When I installed Windows 7 it wouldnt let me it would go through all the installation and then when my computer rebooted it would just be black screen with my mouse, I have tried mulitpule times now, and have just gone backs to Windows Vista, this no longer works and does the same thing as when I tried to insta
I have a Nvidia GTX 275 video card, ASUS m2N-E SLI mother board,and a AMD 5200 Dual core processor

Comment: Its hard to say but Test RAM with Memtest86 or 86+, test HDD with your manufacturers HDD testing software, and strip every unnecessary component from your system while installing thus to minimize issue surface area. Let me know what happens after all this.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your BIOS to factory defaults, if you have more than one stick of RAM in the system, try just installing Windows with just one stick for now.

Also you can see if your BIOS is updated to the latest version.